# communicating with windows service using SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-services, named-pipes

I am looking forward for an example for using a user defined control code in services. I want to send a user defined command to my windows service. At this command windows service will create a named-pipe for client process, and client will establish a connection with this named-pipe by CreateFile function. My custom control sometimes works well but later it shows error for invalidation.

So how can I establish information exchange between a service and various clients?

Answer (score 0):

`SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL` is rarely used. When it is used, it is generally to prompt the service to re-read its configuration file. (On unix SIGHUP is generally used for the same purpose).

In your case the correct answer is to simply create the named pipe on startup and keep listening, and wait for someone to connect if they ever do.